# Jenkins user not in passwd on dynamic jnlp slave in kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am building a system to do c++ cmake builds primarily.  I have Jenkins firing the dynamic pods, firing off shell scripts, etc.  But, I can't get it to checkout the code.  Now, my `Jenkinsfile` launches a container that the actual compile is supposed to be run in.  That "sub" container is tuned to compile C++ code.  Now, I have jenkins running scripts and such in that pod, but, when i try

`checkout scm`

im getting errors saying

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --force --progress git@gitlab.com:mystuff/hello-world-cmake.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: No user exists for uid 1000080000
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

my home folder is the standard `/home/jenkins` and the workspace folder is there, etc, etc.  But, when I dump the `/etc/passwd` file, the `jenkins` user isn't listed in it.

Whats the appropriate way to add the jenkins user to that file?

Answer (score 0):

What image are you using for Jenkins slave? Does it have user jenkins? If it has you need to specify this in your spec for Jenkins slave:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
```

**UPDATE:**

You cannot run default Jenkins image in Openshift, because Openshift runs containers as random user. You should run Jenkins from builtin Jenkins template "Jenkins Persistent". If you don't have this template and don't have Jenkins image stream - you can try to use image `openshift/jenkins-2-centos7`. See details at:

https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/issues/168

https://github.com/openshift/jenkins

Comment: I’m using the standard published image from the Jenkins team.  Thanks, I’ll look at this tomorrow.  Should I map that to a service account in okd?

Comment: Ugh, I was hoping to avoid that cuz they are very slow in doing updates.  But I will swap out images and see if that helps.  Thanks

Comment: ok, progress.  I switched everything over from my helm chart to the openshift template.  Now my problem is the jnlp container can clone the repo from gitlab just fine, but i have another container in the same pod.  that second has the same issue as before, and no user 1000.